# Hibernate error while inserting new rows: CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I created a spring boot application, which use postgresql database with hibernate.
Database connection is OK, inserting rows works properly for a while.
There is a method, which insert a lot row in a for loop, it also seems good, but after a while I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:812) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:799) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:162) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

What is the solution for this exception?

Comment: Looks like you are creating a new connection for each insert. Can you provide a sample code ?

Comment: Yes, I use CrudRepository to save the object.
I create a lot of SampleEntity and add to a list and then I iterate in the list and save it.
for(SampleEntity sampleEntity : sampleEntities){
    sampleRepository.save(sampleEntity);
}
sampleRepository is @Autowired to the class.

Comment: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
Are you sure about your username and password for your jdbc connection?

Comment: Yes, my username and password is OK. When I call the save method only one time, it's working.

Comment: Try -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: You could populate the entire list and use saveAll instead of save-per-entity

Comment: Maybe the permission denied is because you reach the number of max allowed connections (either of the database or of the web server). Maybe it is due to a misconfigurations that makes you open a new connection for each entity instead of having everything in a single transaction?